# Finding UDP ports on Windows host

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, command-line

Does anyone know of a successful way to discover open UDP ports without using third party applications. So either by netstat or other method?

Comment: Thank you. That was really helpful. Never thought about using the performance monitor.

Comment: You can also pipe the netstat output to a text file.